# How can I change ColorTween begin or end color with setState?

Tags: flutter, animation

This is a widget for my quiz app. I am currently working on the quiz option button.
I want it to blink green or red whether the answer is true or not.
But it's not working. I tried different things but I couldn't succeed.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestButton extends StatefulWidget {
  TestButton({this.text, this.color, this.onPressed});
  final Function onPressed;
  final Color color;
  final String text;

  @override
  _TestButtonState createState() => _TestButtonState();
}

class _TestButtonState extends State<TestButton> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation _animation;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400));

    _animation = ColorTween(begin: Colors.transparent, end: widget.color)
        .animate(CurvedAnimation(curve: Curves.decelerate, parent: _animationController))
          ..addListener(() {
            setState(() {   
            });
          });

    _animationController.addStatusListener((status) {
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
        _animationController.reverse();
      } else if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
        _animationController.forward();
      }
    });
    _animationController.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return SizedBox(
      width: width / 1.3,
      child: InkWell(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
        onTap: widget.onPressed,
        child: Container(
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(width / 20),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: _animation.value,
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.white38),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
            child: Text(
              widget.text,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontFamily: "Fondamento"),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the usage of the button. I am applying a setState function but it doesn't make sense. The problem is that the animation works but the setState function doesn't change the color value in the ColorTween

```
TestButton(
              text: question.optionA,
              color: colorA,//Colors.transparent
              onPressed: () {
                if (canTap) {
                  canTap = false;
                  if (question.answer == 1) {
                    setState(() {
                      colorA = Colors.green;
                    });
                  } else {
                    setState(() {
                      colorA = Colors.red;
                    });
                  }
                }
              },
            ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove this part:

```dart
          ..addListener(() {
            setState(() {   
            });
          });
```

And use AnimatedBuilder like this:

```dart
    return SizedBox(
      width: width / 1.3,
      child: InkWell(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
        onTap: widget.onPressed,
        child: Container(
          child: AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: _animationController,
            builder: (_, __) => Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(width / 20),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: _animationController.value,
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.white38),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
              child: Text(
                widget.text,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontFamily: "Fondamento"),
              ),
            )
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it has worked. Is this the best solution for coding efficiency?

Comment: @MustafaHakan I would suggest extending `AnimatedWidget` instead, but this solution is pretty decent

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `didUpdateWidget` to reset `_animation` 
In working demo, when click button, `color` changes from `red` to `green`

```
@override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant TestButton oldWidget) {
    if (oldWidget.color != widget.color) {
      _animation = ColorTween(begin: Colors.transparent, end: widget.color)
          .animate(CurvedAnimation(
              curve: Curves.decelerate, parent: _animationController))
            ..addListener(() {
              setState(() {});
            });
    }
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestButton extends StatefulWidget {
  TestButton({this.text, this.color, this.onPressed});
  final Function onPressed;
  final Color color;
  final String text;

  @override
  _TestButtonState createState() => _TestButtonState();
}

class _TestButtonState extends State<TestButton> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation _animation;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400));

    _animation = ColorTween(begin: Colors.transparent, end: widget.color)
        .animate(CurvedAnimation(
            curve: Curves.decelerate, parent: _animationController))
          ..addListener(() {
            setState(() {});
          });

    _animationController.addStatusListener((status) {
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
        _animationController.reverse();
      } else if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
        _animationController.forward();
      }
    });
    _animationController.forward();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant TestButton oldWidget) {
    if (oldWidget.color != widget.color) {
      _animation = ColorTween(begin: Colors.transparent, end: widget.color)
          .animate(CurvedAnimation(
              curve: Curves.decelerate, parent: _animationController))
            ..addListener(() {
              setState(() {});
            });
    }
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return SizedBox(
      width: width / 1.3,
      child: InkWell(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
        onTap: widget.onPressed,
        child: Container(
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(width / 20),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: _animation.value,
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.white38),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
            child: Text(
              widget.text,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontFamily: "Fondamento"),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Color colorA = Colors.red;
  bool canTap = true;
  int answer = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            TestButton(
              text: "question.optionA",
              color: colorA, //Colors.transparent
              onPressed: () {
                if (canTap) {
                  canTap = false;
                  if (answer == 1) {
                    setState(() {
                      colorA = Colors.green;
                    });
                  } else {
                    setState(() {
                      colorA = Colors.red;
                    });
                  }
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution is worked for me. Thanks for your help. But I am not sure if this is the best way to make this animation. I'll try other solution too.

Comment: @MustafaHakan, it's a fix for the bug of your current code and question.